# Python AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get_price'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm building a Discord.py bot that will send Eth Gas Prices. Here is what I have so far:

```
import discord
import os 
import requests
import json


client = discord.Client()

def get_price():
  response = requests.get_price
  ("https://www.ethgasstationapi.com/api/standard")
  if response.status_code != 200:
    print('! Error to load URL')
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  price = jason_data
  return(price)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

    if message.content.startswith('?price'):
     price = get_price()
     await message.channel.send(price)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

It's returning the error:

> Python AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get_price'

Can some help? Thanks

Comment: Rename - requests.get_price( -> requests.get(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the get() method of requests

```
response = requests.get("https://www.ethgasstationapi.com/api/standard")
```

and take care of your typo

```
 #price = jason_data #wrong

 price = json_data
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I'd upvote but my account is still too new.

Answer (score 0):

This line is a mistake.
`response = requests.get_price`- requests don't have an attribute get_price. Probably `requests.get(url)` is the thing you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Request doesn't have a get_price method, try this,

```
response = requests.get("https://www.ethgasstationapi.com/api/standard")
```